# Python BigQuery API - get table schema

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to fetch schema form bigquery table. Given a sample code like

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

client =  bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')

def test_extract_schema(client): 
    project = 'bigquery-public-data'
    dataset_id = 'samples'
    table_id = 'shakespeare'

    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API Request

    # View table properties
    print(table.schema)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_extract_schema(client)
```

This is returning value like:

`[SchemaField('word', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED', 'A single unique word (where whitespace is the delimiter) extracted from a corpus.', ()), SchemaField('word_count', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED', 'The number of times this word appears in this corpus.', ()), SchemaField('corpus', 'STRING', 'REQUIRED', 'The work from which this word was extracted.', ()), SchemaField('corpus_date', 'INTEGER', 'REQUIRED', 'The year in which this corpus was published.', ())]`

Where I am trying to capture schema only in the format like

```
'word' 'STRING','word_count' INTEGER'
```

Is there any way to get this using API call or any other method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always get the `table.schema` variable and iterate over it, since the table is a list made of [SchemaField](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField.html?highlight=SchemaField) values:

```
result = ["{0} {1}".format(schema.name,schema.field_type) for schema in table.schema]
```

Result for that same dataset and table:

```
['word STRING', 'word_count INTEGER', 'corpus STRING', 'corpus_date INTEGER']
```

Comment: I am getting 'AttributeError: 'TableListItem' object has no attribute 'schema''

Answer (score 3):

[here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableListItem.html), `schema` has been expired.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is, after you have your client and table instances, to do something like this:

```
import io
f = io.StringIO("")
client.schema_to_json(table.schema, f)
print(f.getvalue())
```

Comment: This worked avoiding lot of looping in to get the desired schema.