# How to get column name from BigQuery API?

Tags: google-bigquery

I can get column values using the following codes:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'C:\\Users\xxx\Desktop\key.json'
bq_client = Client()
query = "SELECT msts, coreuserid, spend_usd FROM `project.f_purchase` where dt = '2019-04-02' limit 5"
query_job = bq_client.query(query)
results = query_job.result()   

for row in results:
    print("{}, {}, {}".format(row.msts, row.uid, row.spend_amount))
```

But as shown in the last row, this requires direct column name. Now I have multiple queries and I want to run them in a look and display the result. Is there a way like `.format(row.column1, row.column2...)`? In addition, number of result columns are different for the queries.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per BigQuery [Python client documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) you can loop over the row object as follow without specifying the exact column name:

```py
for row in query_job:  # API request - fetches results
    # Row values can be accessed by field name or index
    assert row[0] == row.name == row["name"]
    print(row)
```

In addition, you can always use the [SchemaField values](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.schema.SchemaField.html) as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908479/1031958)

```
result = ["{0} {1}".format(schema.name,schema.field_type) for schema in table.schema]
```

This is an example using a BigQuery public dataset on how to access fields without specifying the field name:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from pprint import pprint
import json

client = bigquery.Client()

query = (
    "SELECT state,max(gender) as gender FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` "
    'GROUP BY state '
    "LIMIT 10"
)
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
    location="US",
)  # API request - starts the query

for num, row in enumerate(query_job, start=1):  # API request - fetches results
    # Row values can be accessed by field name or index
    # assert row[0] == row.name == row["name"]
    print("{} AS {}, {} AS {}".format(row[0], query_job._query_results._properties['schema']['fields'][0]['name'], row[1], query_job._query_results._properties['schema']['fields'][1]['name']))

    #print(row[0], row[1])

print(json.dumps(query_job._query_results._properties['schema']['fields'][0]['name']))
print(query_job._query_results._properties)
#pprint(vars(query_job._query_results._properties))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
superQuery:bin tamirklein$ python test.py
AK AS state, M AS gender
AL AS state, M AS gender
AR AS state, M AS gender
AZ AS state, M AS gender
CA AS state, M AS gender
CO AS state, M AS gender
CT AS state, M AS gender
DC AS state, M AS gender
DE AS state, M AS gender
FL AS state, M AS gender
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm still a little confused: 1) I can use a nested loop to print all columns using index. If I want to print the column name as well, how to do that? It seems both `row.name` and `row["name"]` still requires exact field name....   2) It seems `schema` only works for a table, do I have to store the result of my query in a temporary table?   Sorry if I misunderstand anything...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed example. What I want to do is to use a variable to instead the exact field name. Like `print("{0} AS {2}, {1} AS {3}".format(row[0], row[1], field_name[0], field_name[1]))`....

Comment: I updated my answer to help you get the schema fields and also gave you some ideas on how to inspect the `query_job` if you need anything else. I believe this should now help you print the data as you have asked

Comment: @user2894829 hope my efforts were useful to you and you managed to solve your problem. Appreciate if you can accept my answer and vote-up if applicable

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and patience. It works and I have accepted. The last question is....I did not find any example like `query_job._query_results._properties['schema']['fields'][0]['name']` in the API document, how do you know this usage? Read the source code?

Comment: Sure. I usually find BigQuery rest API documentation to be very helpful. I use this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query

Answer (score 5):

You can also cast the row in your for loop into dict (by `dict(row)`). Then keys are the column names and you can do whatever you can do with the dictionary -- iterate over the keys (column names), values (column values) or both together, without the need to know the column names explicitly up-front.