# list_datasets() method does nothing in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-bigquery

I am trying to get the list of datasets from BigQuery inside the AWS lambda. But, while executing the `client.list_datasets()` method it does nothing and lambda is timed out.

My code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            service_account_dict)

client = Client(
            project=service_account_dict.get("project_id"),
            credentials=credentials
        )

datasets = client.list_datasets()
print(datasets)

for dataset in datasets:
    print("dataset info", dataset.__dict__)
```

The output of first print statement is:

`<google.api_core.page_iterator.HTTPIterator object at 0x7fbae4975550>`

But, the second print for `dataset.__dict__` is not being printed. Or, looping over the `HTTPIterator` object is not performed.

**BTW, the code works perfectly fine in local machine.**

Comment: Does your Lambda function have proper network access?

Comment: @ArkaMukherjee Yes, Lambda function has proper network access. It's inside a VPC but, I've set up security group which allows all outbound traffic.

Comment: I would try to investigate the size and other details of dataset and see if you are getting an error object as well

Comment: @TamirKlein, the output of `datasets.__dict__` is like this `{'_started':False,'client':<google.cloud.bigquery.client.Clientobjectat..>,'item_to_value':<function_item_to_datasetat..>,'max_results':None,'page_number':0,'next_page_token':None,'num_results':0,'api_request':functools.partial(<boundmethodClient._call_apiof<google.cloud.bigquery.client.Clientobjectat...>>,<google.api_core.retry.Retryobjectat...>),'path':'/projects/firebase-test/datasets','_items_key':'datasets','extra_params':{'all':True},'_page_start':<function_do_nothing_page_startat...>,'_next_token':'nextPageToken'}`

Comment: As you can see the api return zero (0) result. Can you print this item on your local machine and compare the result. Also are you sure your service account are correctly uploaded to the lambda node container?

Comment: @TamirKlein, Running it locally also gives the same output (i.e. `num_results` is zero (0)). But, I can iterate through the `datasets` and access each dataset info in my local machine.

Comment: Your lambda not returning an answer since there is an error and no res200 or res500 is returned. So now the obvious question is why. You will need to add more print log in your for loop which unfortunately I can't do for you to find the problem. In this answer I put some ideas how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757161/1031958 hope this will help you find the issue.

Comment: It was actually the VPC which was causing the issue. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS VPC that I used in lambda function was causing this issue. The VPC blocked requests to the external API (in my case BigQuery API).

Configuring the VPC subnet and NAT Gateway to expose lambda function to the internet (0.0.0.0/0) solved the issue.