# How do I get a node.js lambda function to write to postgresql and return the error/response?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, lambda

I'm trying to build an API using AWS Lambda & node.js which writes a record into a postgres database. I then want to return the response from the db back as the API response.

I can get write action to work from my laptop, but not as a Lambda function. It just doesn't seem to execute the client.query function. I think this is because the event.handler runs asynchronously but I'm stuck on how to make this work.

Secondly I want to pass the res or err back out of the client.query function so I can return it as the API response. I can't figure out how to get those out of the query function even running locally.

I thought declaring response at the start would make it global but whilst debugging it is undefined at the point where I'm trying to return it.

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

var response

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const query = {
        text: "insert into testTwo (test) values($1)",
        values: [body.text],
    }

    const client = new Client({
        user: '',
        host: '',
        database: '',
        password: '',
        port: 5432,
    });
    client.connect();

    client.query(query, (err,res) => {
        console.log("Why doesn't this execute?");
        if (err) {
            response = {
                statusCode: 400,
                body: JSON.stringify(err)
            };
        } else {
            response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify(res)
            };
        }
    client.end();

    });

    return response;

};
```

Comment: Can you wrap this line `client.connect();` in `try/catch` and confirm the connection is correctly established since if not this can cause the issues you are describing

Comment: I tried this and nothing gets logged either locally or as lambda function. I then tried adding a call back instead. Running locally I can see the connection being made successfully. In Lambda nothing gets logged, neither error nor success.

Comment: Where do you host your postgresql server? It seems your Lambda doesn't have access to this server. Another option is that your Lambda is in a VPC and your internet connection is blocked (See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55843346/1031958) as an example)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this - I eventually figured it out and got it working.

Answer (score 3):

OK So I eventually got it working, though this isn't perfect as it doesn't deal with errors in the SQL yet.

The mistake was using the callback function instead of using client.query as a promise. By adding await to the promise it kept Lambda running until the query resolved.

Working code as follows:

```
exports.handler = async(event) => {

    const {Client} = require('pg');

    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const query = {
        text: "insert into test (text) values($1)",
        values: [body.text],
    };

    const client = new Client({
        //credentials
    });

    client.connect();

    const result = await client.query(query);
    const resultString = JSON.stringify(result);    

    client.end();

    const response = {
        "statusCode":200,
        "body":resultString
    };

    return response;

};
```